# Optimisation of a "search and grab" sh script

Tags: bash, loops

Here is a script which used to be working fine, but as now I'm dealing with a huge number of inodes (about 400K), it seems to produce some I/O slownesses.
The script reads a definition file "def" which is a list of identifiers, and for each of the 400K files in the "dir" directory, it appends the whole file content if one of the identifiers is found in the 4 first lines to the end of a "def" specific file.

```
#!/bin/sh
for def in *.def
do
        touch $def.out
        for file in $dir/*
        do
                if head -4 $file | grep -q -f  $def
                then
                        cat $file >> $def.out
                fi
        done
done
```

How can I make it a way faster?

Comment: I would try to spread the 400k in the dir directory into a few subdirectories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution. It should be much faster than your script, because

1. It creates a regex from each .def file. It does not read each .def file more than once.
2. It uses `opendir` to read the directory contents. It is much faster than doing a `*` glob, but as a penalty, the files are not sorted. To compare the output of your and mine script, you have to use

   ```
   diff <(sort $def.out) <(sort $def-new.out)
   ```

   You can replace the `opendir` by a `glob` to get exactly the same output. It slows the script, but it is still much faster than the old one.

The script is here:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = 'd';              # Enter your dir here.

my @regexen;
my @defs = glob '*.def';
for my $def (@defs) {
    open my $DEF,   '<', $def           or die "$def: $!";
    open my $TOUCH, '>', "$def-new.out" or die "$def-new.out: $!";
    my $regex = q();
    while (<$DEF>) {
        chomp;
        $regex .= "$_|"
    }
    substr $regex, -1, 1, q();
    push @regexen, qr/$regex/;
}

# If you want the same order, uncomment the following 2 lines and comment the next 2 ones.
#
# for my $file (glob "$dir/*") {
#     $file =~ s%.*/%%;

opendir my $DIR, $dir or die "$dir: $!";
while (my $file = readdir $DIR) {
    next unless -f "$dir/$file";

    my %matching_files;
    open my $FH, '<', "$dir/$file" or die "$dir/$file: $!";
    while (my $line = <$FH>) {
        last if $. > 4;
        my @matches = map $line =~ /$_/ ? 1 : 0, @regexen;
        $matching_files{$_}++ for grep $matches[$_], 0 .. $#defs;
    }

    for my $i (keys %matching_files) {
        open my $OUT, '>>', "$defs[$i]-new.out" or die "$defs[$i]-new.out: $!";
        open my $IN,  '<',  "$dir/$file"        or die "$dir/$file: $!";
        print $OUT $_ while <$IN>;
        close $OUT;
    }
}
```

### Updated

A file can now be fetched several times. Instead of creating one huge regex, an array of regexen is created and they are matched against one by one.

Comment: It does not matter if the outputs are not sorted. Your script is terrific. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I have a doubt. Does your script allow to fetch several times the same file when a common pattern is found in several $def files? I'd need this.

Comment: @LostInTranslation: Test it. Create simplified files, run your old and my new script and compare the results.

Comment: So, after making a toy example, I confirm that behavior. A file in $dir is never grabbed more than once and, if a $def file is the first in the folder to list patternA, it would be the only one to grab all the files with patternA to "its name". My perl skills are too weak to find what modification to do though. My only idea using your script is to run it for each $def file separately. It would be still better than my former bash solution, but if you have a good idea, I'm ready to listen.

Comment: It worked in 2 hours instead of about 15 days (estimated) with my naive bash script: thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found that I start to see some performance problems when I have more than 10,000 files in a single folder.  When that happens, even the `ls` command can take seconds to return.

Your script seems to be inherently IO heavy.  it is looking at lots of files and creating or appending to lots of files.   I don't see anything you can improve without changing how the script operates.

If you can, move some of this data into a database.  Databases can be tuned more easily to this scale of data than the filesystem.

Comment: Indeed, the `ls` command is struggling once entering that "dir" folder. This db suggestion makes sense, but as I need to do that something like once a year, I'm not sure I want to spend a significant amount of my time to earn something like 2 days of computer time.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a lot of forks; one fork saved in the loop makes a total of 400K forks for the whole script. Here's what I would do.

Instead of a touch for each *.def, touch them in big chunks:

```
find . -name '*.def' | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1.out/' | xargs touch
```

(If your find supports it, use `find . -maxdepth 1` ...)

Instead of a two command pipe, do it in a single command:

```
if awk "NR <= 4 && /$def/ { exit 0 } NR==5 { exit 1 }" $file; then
```

(Check your $def if it doesn't contain meta-characters, though. A dot should be ok.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Actually, the number of $def files is about 20 then the "touch" step is not critical in my case. I think I could indeed improve my latency issue if I could remove a pipe (then the use of 2 programs: head + grep), however I was maybe not clear enough but my $def files are files that contain hundreds of "patterns" each instead of a single like I think you understood referring to your awk command. That's why I use `grep -f`.

Comment: Aah, I confused -f with -F for fgrep.